# Redirección a fichero en Bash borra contenido antiguo

Tags: bash, unix

Estoy desarrollando un programa en Bash que contiene estas líneas para encriptar un fichero en rot13:

```
base64 $1 > Encripte                         
cat Encripte | tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-Za-Mn-za-m' > Encripte
```

No tiene ningún error ni nada de sintaxis.

Yo le paso un archivo con texto y la primera linea me lo encripta y me lo guarda en el fichero.

Ahora bien, en la segunda línea no sé por qué que me borra el fichero.

¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Answer (score 5):

En redirecciones, `>` significa **sobreescribir**. Es decir, eliminar cualquier contenido previo del archivo destino.

Que es muy diferente a lo que tú quieres, que sería **añadir al final**, sin eliminar el contenido anterior. Para ello, se usa `>>`:

```
base64 $1 > Encripte                         
cat Encripte | tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-Za-Mn-za-m' >> Encripte
```

Comment: Muchas gracias al final era eso

Comment: ¿Seguro que quieres añadir al final, @CarlosWindows? Es decir, lo que dice Trauma es correctísimo, pero me resulta raro que quieras añadir la encriptación en el mismo fichero de origen.

Answer (score 3):

A este caracter `>` se le asocia lo que se le llama "redirección". Lo que este mecanismo hace es que redirige la salida de un comando hacía un otro comando o archivo. En realidad, lo único que hace es modificar la dirección de los flujos estandar (entrada estandar, salida estandar o error estandar), y darle un tratamiento especial al archivo de la derecha.

Hay varias sabores de redirecciónes, por ejemplo:

- `>`, que redirecciona la salida estandar de un comando a un archivo, **truncando el archivo de la derecha** (lo trunca al tamaño cero)
- `>>`, que redirecciona la salida de un comando a otro a un archivo pero en modo `append`, es decir, busca el final de archivo, y sobre ese añade el contenido obtenido
- `<`, redirecciona la salida estandar de un archivo en al derecha hacia la entrada estandar del comando de la izquierda
- `2>`, redirige la el error estandar del comando de la izquierda, y **trunca al tamaño cero el archivo de la derecha* para escribir en el este el error estandar
- `2>>`, redirige el error estandar del comando de la izquierda pero busca el final del archivo de la derecha y **añade** a este su contenido
- `&>`, redirecciona tanto el error estandar como la salida estandar del comando de la izquierda al archivo de la derecha pero *antes* truncándolo a tamaño cero
- `&>>`, lo mismo que lo anterior pero sin truncarlo, sino añadiéndolo
- `<<`, a esto se le conoce como *here-document*
- `<<<`, a esto se le conoce como *here-string*

Revisemos que es lo que hace tu segundo pipeline:

```
$ cat Encripte | tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-Za-Mn-za-m' > Encripte
```

Lo que sucede aquí es que se ejecutan dos comandos de manera parelela. Por un lado, `cat Encripte`, por el otro, `tr ... > Encripte`, puesto eso es lo que hacen los *pipelines*. En el primero se lee de este, mientras que en el segundo, se abre en modo escritura, es decir, se trunca a tamaño cero para luego escribir en este. Esto se hace de manera independiente la una de la otra. Lo único que lo relaciona directamente son los flujos estandar de entrada y salida.

Por ejemplo, supón que creamos el archivo Encripte con: `$ echo contenido > Encripte`, después corremos ambos comandos pero con una diferencia de un segundo entre estos:

```
$ { sleep 0 && cat Encripte; } | { sleep 1 && tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m' > Encripte; }
```

Al revisar el contenido del archivo:

```
$ cat Encripte
pbagravqb
```

Tenemos que todo funciona como debería, y es porque, a razón de que pusimos una diferencia de tiempo en estos, primero se ejecutó la letura de Encripte, y después la apertura para escritura. Es decir, partimos desde la certeza de que sabíamos que no es secuencial.

Sin embargo, si intercambiásemos los números de `sleep`. Se truncaría.

Una ventaja de aprovechar lo asíncrono, es que, a diferencia de las respuetas dadas, **no creamos y eliminamos archivos extra**.

En el caso de que quieras hacer algo de este estilo:

```
$ comando1 archivo1 > archivo1
```

Ahora ya sabemos que primero se abre el archivo1 en modo escritura y entonces se trunca este, luego este archivo (ahora vació) es usado por el comando `comando1`. Es decir, `comando1`, de esta manera, siempre leerá un archivo vacío, recién truncado.

Pero ahora que ya sabemos esto, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
$ echo $(comando1 archivo1) > archivo1
```

Puesto que lo que se ejecute en el *command-substitution*, se ejecutará primero por el [orden de precedencia establecido en Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion), después vendrán las redirecciones. Es decir, primero sucederá lo que esté dentro, pasando todo el output y redirigiéndolo al archivo en modo escritura. Así aseguramos que, a pesar de que eliminamos el contenido de archivo1, le pasaremos el contenido procesado que obtuvimos anteriormente de este.

**De esta manera nos evitamos hacer archivos extra**.

Por ejemplo:

```
$ echo $(tr "o" "a" < Encripte) > Encripte
```

Comment: interesante respuesta, pero ¿por qué es malo usar archivos extra incluso siendo temporales? Sugiero también que hagas preguntas y respuestas canónicas con estos temas, ofreces informaciones utilisimas

Answer (score 2):

Cuando ejecutas un comando de la forma `comando fichero1 > fichero2` lo que el sistema hace es:

1. `> fichero2`, es decir trunca el "fichero2".
2. Ejecuta `comando` cogiendo los datos de "fichero1".
3. Dirige la salida al fichero "fichero2" indicado.

En tu caso, "fichero1" es el mismo que "fichero2". Y como en el punto 1. has truncado el fichero, cuando va a ejecutar `comando` (`cat ... | tr '...'`) contra él, se encuentra con algo vacío, por lo que no tiene nada que dar como resultado y obtienes un resultado vacío.

---

Para evitar este problema puedes redirigir la salida a otro fichero y luego moverlo al fichero de origen:

```
comando fichero > fichero_tmp && mv fichero_tmp fichero
```